# Android ordering list by date using Comparator

Tags: java, android, datetime, comparator

I have an arraylist containing arraylists of objects

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> arrayLists
```

Each arraylist contains a datetime string object, I am attempting to convert the datetime string to a date and use Comparator to reorder the list based on the newest to oldest date, I have used this successfully to reorder integers in the past but I seem to be missing something to reorder datetime strings, I have posted my code below

```
            Collections.sort(arrayLists,
                new Comparator<ArrayList<Object>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(ArrayList<Object> a, ArrayList<Object> b) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

                        Date date1, date2;

                        date1 = null;
                        date2 = null;

                        try {

                            date1 = dateFormat.parse((String) a.get(2));
                            date2 = dateFormat.parse((String) b.get(2));

                            Log.d("dateformat", date1.toString() + " " + date2.toString());

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return Long.compare(date1.getTime(),date2.getTime());
                        //return ((Integer) a.get(0)).compareTo((Integer) b.get(0));

                    }

                });
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data which contained in `ArrayList<Object>`

Comment: @Msp the arraylist contains objects that are strings/integers, the third value is always a datetime string in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" format

Comment: What is the issue here? Sorting not happening or some exception is coming . Post sample input and output.

Comment: I tried you code with some samples and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is the string values which are stored in `object.get(2)`. You are creating the parser like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Here, the parser would expect a string like `2015-12-12T12:23:34`. If you pass string with single quotes, like `2015-12-12'T'12:23:34`, it will not work.

So, remove single quotes from all your strings.